# Ubuntu Touch - Screen resolution

Tags: ubuntu-touch, display-resolution

Yesterday, I received my new Ubuntu tablet. Nice piece of kit.

On some of the screens/apps the wording and frame sizes are very small, sometimes too small to read. Where is the setting to increase the screen resolution/size? As there is nothing I can see in settings.

Comment: Have you looked for a DPI setting?

Comment: I did have a look but it all seemed to be around install Ubuntu Tweaks. Do I have to do this on the tablet? If that is the cases, strange there is nothing in the settings to cater for people with sight problems.

Comment: It would perhaps be helpful if you could clarify where you think the sizes are too small. Is this only in legacy apps?

Comment: The first time I noticed it was when I clicked on Firefox. The address bar text and all other text at the top is far too small to even see clearly. The address bar is too small to click on and enter the url of where you want to go. When you click on Gedit, the wording at the top is far to small to even be able to navigate around. This was the case with Libra Office, the Close or the cross was too small to click on to close it. This is whilst using the tablet view. If they are not meant for tablet view, then a discerner may help.

Comment: I have noticed that the XChat app too is hard to read, the text. Like I say, I am not sure if this is because it is only meant to be viewed on a bigger screen on desktop mode. The funny thing though is that the keyboard font size is fine, for example when you enter your pass-code in the tablet to unlock it and entering website url's.

Comment: a little late but yes it is because those apps are meant to be viewed on a bigger screen. you can tweak it with the libertine tweak tool, assuming you installed those apps in libertine